# BOM character in the middle of XML file

Tags: xml

Our application processes files in the [TBX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TermBase_eXchange) format, which is an XML file.  We noticed that a third party application adds the UTF-8 BOM character (`EF BB BF`) in the value of a child element (i.e `<term>[BOM]Value text</term>`).

I thought that the BOM character was only intended to be used at the beginning of a file, indicating the encoding of the whole file.

Is that placing of the [BOM] character correct in an XML file or can we consider the file as corrupted?

If the placing is correct according to the XML specification, should we consider the [BOM] character as:

a) Part of the textual value of the element

OR

b) An ad-hoc indication of the encoding for the element in question (and only for that element and its child elements)

Answer (score 0):

You can check your resulting XML file for validity on various online services like [www.validator.w3.org](http://www.validator.w3.org), [www.xmlvalidation.com](http://www.xmlvalidation.com) and so on